# How to let only 4 values after dot in all values of a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to merge two dataframes with common columns similar to the example:

`Df 1 :         Column A |  Column B
              234.345564  43.234338
              234.345882  23.454138
              212.348762  98.454387
              123.349834  43.452338
Df 2 :         Column A     |   Column B
              234.345564123  43.2343384313
              234.345882543  23.4541383413
              212.348762113  98.4543872343
              123.349834458  43.4523383414`

But as you can see, the incertanty in one is bigger to the other. So I'm trying to keep only the first 4 numbers after the dot, in both Dataframe's columns, so that when I merge them more numbers will correspond to each other.

They would then, be like this:

`Df 1 :        Column A | Column B
              234.3455   43.2343
              234.3458   23.4541
              212.3487   98.4543
              123.3498   43.4523
Df 2 :        Column A | Column B
              234.3455   43.2343
              234.3458   23.4541
              212.3487   98.4543
              123.3498   43.4523`

I've worked with the functions I'm listing below before, but I don't know how to aply them here.

`.append(pl[0:pl.find('.')])
[f'{i}-{int(j)}' for i, j in map(lambda x: x.split('-'), segunda_lista)]`

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

If your data are numeric, you can do:

```
df2 = df2.apply(pd.Series.round, decimals=4)
```

Or if your data is text:

```
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: x.str.extract('^(\d*(\.\d{,4})?)')[0])
```

Output:

```
       ColA     ColB
0  234.3456  43.2343
1  234.3459  23.4541
2  212.3488  98.4544
3  123.3498  43.4523
```

Comment: So, his resolution aplies to all columns of the dataframe? If I have some columns that are strings and other integers, then would this lines still work? Thank you, btw ;)